# ESLint and prettier doesn't like i18n in .ejs files

Tags: node.js, sublimetext3, ejs, eslint, prettier

I'm adding internalization to one of my projects, and facing the issue with eslint, *.ejs and i18n.

```
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/products">
            <i class="ni ni-tv-2 text-primary"></i> <%= __('Products')%>
          </a>
        </li>
```

gives me the errors:

```
eslint: error
prettier/prettier - Replace `·__('Products')` with `__('Products');⏎`

eslint: error
no-undef - '__' is not defined.
```

Trying to find some already existed integrations of eslint with i18n and ejs and no luck yet.

Any recommendations how to fix it?

PS. editor: sublime 3, lang: nodejs

Comment: I‘ve seen the  `__()`  function in PHP projects, are you sure you‘re not mixing up two things?

Comment: what do you mean? I'm not working with PHP for more than 10 years already. We are talking about nodejs + ejs here

Comment: Does prettier work at all with ejs? You can add a `.prettierignore` file with `*.ejs`